# Exclusion Script with Multiple DEs

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, exclusion-script

Can you use multiple DEs in an exclusion script for journey sends? I am currently using this template:

`ROWCOUNT(LOOKUPROWS("DE", "Email", emailaddr))> 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can just add an `AND` statement to this to include more than one lookuprows. Keep in mind though that the more lookups, etc. that you do, the larger the processing draw and the slower your sends - potentially leading to timeout errors.

`ROWCOUNT(LOOKUPROWS("DE1", "Email", emailaddr))> 0 AND ROWCOUNT(LOOKUPROWS("DE2", "Email", emailaddr))> 0`